# Exclude a package from react-native link

Tags: react-native

How do I link all packages except one using `react-native link` ?

I want to run it so that every package except `react-native-vector-icons` links and makes changes in the native files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this directly but you can, at least for IOS, open the Project's "Build Phases" tab and look in the "Link Binary with Libraries" dropdown, from which you can manually delete the undesired linked library. This won't delete any files, just the link.